# .Net Event Handlers priority

Tags: vb.net

I am having the library in C#.Net. If I am creating the form in C# and adding listeners to the C#.Net library object the event handlers called immediately. IF I am creating the form in VB.net and adding listeners to the C#.Net library object, the handlers are called after some time. Do we have any priority to be set the event handlers

Comment: Event handlers don't have priorities in .NET.  What do you mean when you say "the handlers are called after some time?"  What events are you handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have any priority to be set the event handlers

No.  Event handlers are just a delegate that gets run by the class raising the event.  There is no priority.

The event, and the event handlers, should behave the same in C# as in VB.Net.